# Parallax on FullScreen Slider HomePage

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, parallax, parallax.js

I'm developing this website:

http://cslab.com.ve/tkp/

It has a homepage fullscreen I'm trying to make the next div sit over the first with parallax effects when I scroll down.

Im using parallax.js jquery plugin

Now they do it but the NAVBAR is still moving with the page

Something Like This  http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/elision/

Im Using Revolution Slider 4.6.

But only for slide the text, the background im setting in with the parallax.js

Answer (score 1):

Add the class `fixed` to the Bootstrap nav bar div